# Trouble with updates

Tags: updates

When I attempt to do any updates, I receive the following error message:

```
E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, 
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages, 
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove the Merge List by opening a terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T to launch) and run this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Next, generate a new one by running a simple update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```